# How to set value in object constructor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with my script.

Why my constructor of this object do not know that value of wynik1 is changing and always return "this.A" instead of changing it?

```
var wynik1 = (liczba1 / liczba2) * profil;

function potatos(name, moc, square, A, B, C, D, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.moc = moc;
  this.square = square;
  this.A = A;
  this.B = B;
  this.C = C;
  this.D = D;
  this.price = function() {
    if (wynik1 < 18000) {
      return this.A;
    }
    if (wynik1 < 10000) {
      return this.B;
    }
    if (wynik1 < 5000) {
      return this.C;
    }
    if (wynik1 < 3000) {
      return this.D;
    }
  };
}

const animus = new potatos('nameone', 370, 1.7, 7533, 5670, 4800, 4200);
const anomus = new potatos(' olar', 470, 1.7, 7800, 6900, 5260, 4630);
const atopuso = new potatos('komisuslar', 780, 1.7, 7900, 6080, 5450, 4815);

var prices = (function moc() {
  if (liczba4 == "A") {
    return animus.price(4200, 4000, 3800, 3600);
  }
  if (liczba4 == "B") {
    return anomus.price(4000, 4200, 4600, 5000);
  }
  if (liczba4 == "C") {
    return atopuso.price(4200, 4500, 4800, 5300);
  }
})();
```

Comment: do you hate indentation ?

Comment: Because nowhere in your code are you changing the value of `wynik1`. Chances are, it always meet the condition `< 18000` so will always return `this.A`. A quick fix will be to move the line `(liczba1/liczba2)*profil;` into the function itself, so that it is re-evaluated every time `price()` is called.

Comment: What is `liczba1`, `liczba2`, `liczba4`....? Why the constructor has a `price` parameter which you ignore? Why do you call the `price` method with arguments, when that method does not take any?

Comment: Solution of Terry works perfect. 
Var price is working. Liczba4 is connected to select option a, b, c...

Answer (score 0):

This is because the condition you specified inside `if(wynik1 <18000)` will be true most of the time, use this instead:

```
if(wynik1 <18000 && wynik1 >= 10000)
```